# How to extract URLs from HTML source in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, split

My question is: I have a program that fetches the whole source code of a specified URL. The source code will be saved in a variable.

Part of the source code looks like this:

```
"thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/scontent-fra3-1.blablabla.com\/t51.2885-15\/s640x640\/sh0.08\/e35\/1234567_984778981596410_1107218704_n.jpg","is_video":false,
```

The code is has quite a bunch of those URLs. I want my code to look for the part `"thumbnail_src":"` as a marker for beginning the extraction process and stop the extraction at `","is_video":`

This should be obviously done in a loop until all URLs are being extracted and saved into a listing variable.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Looking at your string: `https:\/\/scontent-fra3-1.blablabla.com\/t51.2885-15\/s640x640\/sh0.08\/e35\/1234567_984778981596410_1107218704_n.jpg` that doesn't look like a valid URL... Was this for show?

Comment: How about this Regex: **"thumbnail_src":"(.*)","**

Comment: You can see it **https://regex101.com/r/hK0xH8/4** there...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get that Regexp into my sourcecode. The one that codexer wrote, which is correct but I am getting eerrors in visual basic net.

```
        Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("thumbnail_src""":    """(.*)""","""is_video")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(sourceString)

    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    End If
```

I tried it this way..and also that way:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("thumbnail_src":"(.*)","is_video")
```

Something is wrong the way I am entering the regex code.

Here is the correct one I need to implement:

https://regex101.com/r/hK0xH8/4

```
thumbnail_src":"(.*)","is_video
```

Comment: You have too many """ .... Dim RG as new Regex("thumbnail_src"":(.*),""is_video")

Comment: Actually to stop with the confusion - lets use escape characters instead ... "thumbnail_src\":(.*),\"is_video"

Comment: Thanks! Now the problem with the regex is that it gets me only one BIG match instead of the multiple links. I can demonstrate the problem here:

https://regex101.com/r/cI6cZ9/2

Comment: Is this all coming in on a single string? ... How are you receiving the text? StreamReader, textfile, etc? .. Also, I am +1 you becuase you are caught in the middle of douchebaggery

Comment: I do it with this code
"New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString"
So I download the whole source code and pass it to a string variable

Comment: I edited my answer to match what you are looking for -- I hope that helps

Comment: added a second method as well

Answer (score -2):

In light of your recent edit I am going to redo this answer.

Since it looks like everything is coming in on one line of text here is how I would handle it.

```
Dim LargetxtLine as String = TheVeryLargylineofText
Dim CommaSplit as String() = LargetxtLine.split(","c)
Dim URLList as New List(of String)
Dim RG as New Regex("\"":\""(.*)\""")

For Each str as String in CommaSplit
     If str.contains("thumbnail_src") Then  
          URLList.Add(RG.Match(str).value)  
     End If
Next
```

This will break up the long line of text into managable chunks and then it uses regex to add it to a list of URL's (URLList)

From there you can do just about anything with a list(of String).

There is another way of doing it without splitting on the ,'s

if you use this Regex

```
"thumbnail_src\"":\""(.*?)\"",\""is_video"
```

Adding the "?" in there turns it into a greedy statement meaning that it will stop at the first occurance.

After that you could create a URLList like this

```
DIM RG as New Regex("thumbnail_src\"":\""(.*?)\"",\""is_video")
Dim URLList as MatchCollection = RG.Matches(reallybigString)
```

It's really personal preference

Comment: Have you tested this `Regex` by chance? If you did, this doesn't work when multiple occurrences are found... Also in your example you are basing it off of a little string, he may have many more... And that code wont compile, look at your `line` declaration **and** RG declaration...

Comment: The regex compiles https://regex101.com/r/tE6xZ9/1 .... In the code you need to use double "s so VS will recognize it as a string.

Comment: Did not say the `Regex` wouldn't compile, I am talking about the code. Also paste the example string multiple times and see how it work's, the `Regex` you posted wont work for multiple instances as I said above...

Comment: Well he should be going line by line through the source code

Comment: Also recommending a solution in `Regex` it might be good to explain this solution as the OP may not know how it intends to work.

Comment: Did you paste the test string multiple times using your suggested regex? How did it work out for you?

Comment: I have no idea how he is reading in all the code, whether it's from a streamreader or if he is doing it from a string(). I answered the question completely given the informaton I have.. He now has the Regex and a practical application on how to use the Regex.

Comment: Also how does you posting regex101 with a "g" varible help him at all you twit - at least I gave him a working solution.

Comment: Anyways OP - If you need more help, update your question and Ill be glad to update the answer.

Comment: Do you know what the `g` does? You can use them, they are called Inline Modifiers... Also why does it seem ethical to name call here, I don't...

Comment: All Im saying is that regex101 doesnt even come close to answering the question (even less than whatever you perieved mine to have). If you think you can answer OP's question better than me, then post your answer. Don't downvote a perfectly good working solution and then hide behind comments.

Comment: `perfectly good working solution` I beg to differ that, it **doesn't compile** and it doesn't work when there could be multiple matches, face it; it's **not perfect**...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102749/discussion-between-nefariis-and-codexer).